# Windows Dev Center - Windows 8.1 Package won't let me remove old appxupload

Tags: uwp, windows-dev-center

I'm trying to update an app for windows 8.1. I've updated this many times before with no issue, but now when I upload a new package and remove the old one, it saves fine and it seems to work fine but in the Submission view, the 'Packages' row keeps showing up as 'Incomplete' (and showing two appx files, as if I haven't removed the old one).

I've tried doing it various different ways, including removing the old package after uploading the new one, removing the old package before removing the new one, and other options, but it's just not working.

I'm sure something's going wrong on their end, just don't know what to do about it.

Comment: I also had same issue, what was i does, remove the old package first without uploading new package and save, then upload new one

Comment: This seems a temporary problem and is ok now, you can check it again. If your issue still exists, you can open a support ticket for help: http://aka.ms/storesupport

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT thanks, works now